# How do I conditionally append a row of Excel data from one sheet to another?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I don't use Excel very often, but I'm hoping there is a fairly straightforward way to get through this. I looked through a number of other solutions involving pasting data from one sheet to another, but I couldn't find anything that would allow me to (1) match a cell from one sheet to another and then (2) conditionally append or concatenate data instead of simply pasting it over.

I have an Excel document with two sheets of data. Both sheets contain a numerical ID column. 
I basically need to match the ID's from Sheet2 to the Sheet1 and then append the row data from Sheet2 to the matching rows from Sheet1. I would imagine it will look something like this:

```
If Sheet2 ColumnA Row1 == Sheet1 ColumnA RowX
  Copy Sheet2 Row1 Columns
  Paste (Append) to Sheet1 RowX (without overwriting the existing columns).
```

Sorry if there is a better way to form this question. I've managed to think myself in circles and now I feel like I have a confused Nigel Tufnel look on my face.

[Update: Updated to clarify cells to be copied.]

Comment: If the match is found in row X then you want to add it to row Z? i.e at a location which is (n+2) where n is the same as X. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing text. By "Sheet1 ColumnA RowX" I'm just referring to any row that matches the data from "Sheet2 ColumnA Row1".

Comment: When you say append, do you mean that if the Cell has "SAMPLE1" then it should append to it so it looks like "SAMPLE1 SAMPLE2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do?

The code is untested. I believe it should work. If you get any errors, let me know and we will take it form there...

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws1LR As Long, ws2LR As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim ws1Rng As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim SearchString

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    '~~> Assuming that ID is in Col A
    '~~> Get last row in Col A in Sheet1
    ws1LR = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '~~> Set the Search Range
    Set ws1Rng = ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws1LR)

    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    '~~> Get last row in Col A in Sheet2
    ws2LR = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Loop through the range in Sheet 2 to match it with the range in Sheet1
    For i = 1 To ws2LR
        SearchString = ws2.Range("A" & i).Value

        '~~> Search for the ID
        Set aCell = ws1Rng.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            LastCol = ws2.Cells(i, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            '~~> Append values
            For j = 2 To LastCol
                ws1.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value = ws1.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value & " " & ws2.Cells(i, j).Value
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
For Each cell2 In Sheet2.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
    For Each cell1 In Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If cell2.Value = cell1.Value Then
            Sheet1.Range("B" & cell1.Row & ":Z" & cell1.Row).Value = Sheet2.Range("B" & cell2.Row & ":Z" & cell2.Row).Value
        End If
    Next cell1
Next cell2
```