# Lookup Name From Sheet2 and Copy Row to Sheet3

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formulas

I currently have 3 sheets. Sheet 1 contains 12 Columns. The first column is the company name, I use sheet2 with a list of company names to lookup sheet 1 Column A.

I did this using VLOOKUP

```
    =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$L,COLUMNS($B2:B2)+1,0),"")
```

This works, however the company name appears multiple times throughout sheet 1.

How would I copy the row each time it occurs?

I am happy for a VBA solution.

Comment: To clarify, you want to copy entire row whenever in Sheet1 is found company name from sheet2?

Comment: Not the entire sheet. Just the row. So If the A3 matches a name within Sheet2, move the entire row from sheet 1 to sheet 3

Comment: You are going to need to use a `For` loop if you want to copy a name if it appears multiple times. Using `VLookup` or `Match` only return the first value found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to effect of this should work. I don't know if all of the columns are the same as in your workbook and as of right now, if there are no headers on sheet 3, your first row on that sheet will be blank. Other than that this seems to work.

```
Public Sub findMatch()
    Dim lastRowS1 As Long, lastRowS2 As Long, lastRowS3 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim tempS1 As String, temps2 As String
    lastRowS1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowS2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To lastRowS1
        tempS1 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Text
        For j = 1 To lastRowS2
            temps2 = Sheet2.Cells(j, 1).Text
            If tempS1 = temps2 Then
                lastRowS3 = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheet3.Rows(lastRowS3 + 1)
                j = lastRowS2
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Try this guy:

```
Public Sub findMatch()
    Dim lastRowS1 As Long, lastRowS2 As Long, lastRowS3 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim tempS1 As String, tempS2 As String, tempRow As Long
    lastRowS1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowS2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To lastRowS1
        tempS1 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Text

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(tempS1, Sheet2.Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
            lastRowS3 = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheet3.Rows(lastRowS3 + 1)

        End If

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Edit: forgot to remove `Debug.Print` that will speed it up some as well.

Comment: Thanks @hessr17. This seems to work very well, however my sheet contains just over 40000 lines and seems to crash my excel. Any ideas?

Comment: Are all of the company names unique? If so, rather than looping through the company name sheet we can do a `Match` in that direction. I will edit the response to show that.

Comment: Yes they are all unique :) Often the same name to start eg Google Head Office and then Google Offsite Location

Comment: Issue I'm having with Match is that it throws an error if there is no match. even with an error handler, the error will pop up on the 2nd time it throws an error.

Comment: Hmm, I see, I can definitely use this method, It just takes 10minutes or so to process each sheet :)

Comment: Do you have any events occurring (ex: Worksheet_Change)? If so, you can turn those off too, those could be slowing down your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at the answer from Siddharth Rout in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930020/how-do-i-conditionally-append-a-row-of-excel-data-from-one-sheet-to-another?rq=1) thread. It's broadly similar to what you want. In short you'd loop through the company names on sheet 2 and use the Find functionality described by Siddharth to locate the matching rows on sheet 1, then move them to the bottom of the populated area on sheet3.

Your need is slightly different in that you want to actually move the content but simply using the Macro Recorder (on the hidden by default Developer tab which you may need to switch on) will give you the VBA syntax for doing a move.