# Matching data from two workbooks based on ID column and updating data in two columns of first workbook where IDs match

Tags: vba, excel, matching

I'm attempting to do something like this:

Workbook 1

```
   B  R   S
   1  22  41
   2  43  22
   4  55  30
   5  72  0
```

Workbook 2

```
    B  R  S
    5  13 43 
    3  34 23
    1  20 4
    2  89 90
```

Workbook 1 (updated after Macro matches IDs in Column B and pastes data from workbook 2 to Columns R & S)

```
   B   R  S
   1   20 4
   2   89 90 
   4   55 30
   5   13 43
```

Essentially I'm trying to match the IDs in column A of the workbooks and have any data in column B and c of workbook 2, in the rows that have the matching IDs, to be pasted over the cells of B and C in workbook 1.

This is the code I've managed to cobble together based on this question [appending data based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930020/how-do-i-conditionally-append-a-row-of-excel-data-from-one-sheet-to-another) (Thanks to the person who asked the question and the person who answered it!)

```
   Sub Update_Worksheet()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws1LR As Long, ws2LR As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim ws1Rng As Range, aCell As Range
Dim SearchString

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
'~~> Assuming that ID is in Col B
'~~> Get last row in Col B in Sheet1
ws1LR = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'~~> Set the Search Range
Set ws1Rng = ws1.Range("B1:B" & ws1LR)

Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
'~~> Get last row in Col B in Sheet2
ws2LR = ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'~~> Loop through the range in Sheet 2 to match it with the range in Sheet1
For i = 1 To ws2LR
    SearchString = ws2.Range("B" & i).Value

    '~~> Search for the ID
    Set aCell = ws1Rng.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '~~> If found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        LastCol = ws2.Cells(i, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

This is the part I feel I have to change, but not sure how to make it overwrite the columns I need to overwrite with the data: (specifically I need columns R & S of sheet 2 to overwrite R&S of Sheet 1 if the IDs in column A match)

```
        '~~> Append values
        For j = 2 To LastCol
            ws1.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value = ws2.Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you are just updating your value, why don't you use Vlookup? You can search each ID from Column B in Workbook 1 and get the results from Workbook 2.

Comment: exactly, use formulas like [VLOOKUP](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function), no need for loops or even a macro, and you can [combine conditional IF statements too](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-use-the-IF-and-VLOOKUP-functions-together-in-Excel)

Comment: and if you only want to copy certain rows [use Autofilter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/quick-start-filter-data-by-using-an-autofilter-08647e19-11d1-42f6-b376-27b932e186e0)

Comment: I'm trying to automate the process as I daily get two worksheets where worksheet 2 comes to me with very similar information as worksheet 1, but worksheet 2 updates columns R&S. 

Will Vlookup automatically match the IDs of the two sheets even if they are not in the same order and have data pasted over the old data in worksheet 1 if the IDs match? Also, will I have to manually put the vlookup formula in every day throughout the columns? Or is there a way to automate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous but form my little understanding i modify this for you.

```
'~~> If found
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    '~~> Append values
        ws1.Cells(aCell.Row, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value
        ws1.Cells(aCell.Row, 18).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 18).Value
        ws1.Cells(aCell.Row, 19).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 19).Value
End If
```

Comment: Sorry if it seemed too ambiguous - I'm trying to match the IDs in column B. 

If there is a match I want to grab the data in the row of the match under columns R & S of worksheet 2 and place them over the data in columns R & S of worksheet 1 in the row of the matching ID. Does that make more sense? Let me know!